# How to save an expandable listview in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have an expandable listview that I can add too. How can I save every item that is added. I have tried using sharedpreferences with gson to json, however that doesn't seem to work. Here is my expandable listview adapter:

```
public class ExpandListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Group> groups;

    public ExpandListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Group> groups) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition,
                   childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
             LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                     .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());

        return convertView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition)
                .getItems();

        return chList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.group_header, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        tv.setText(group.getName());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
```

Here is the class that uses the expandable listview, I can add groups with the AlertDialog and it also adds a child with the name of "Yo", just for testing reasons:

```
public class classesScreen extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private ExpandListAdapter ExpAdapter;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
private Button newHeaderBut;
static ArrayList<Group> group_list;
ArrayList<Child> child_list;
String m_text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_classes);

    group_list = new ArrayList<Group>();

    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.classesListView);
    ExpAdapter = new ExpandListAdapter(this, group_list);
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);


    newHeaderBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newClassBut);

    newHeaderBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(classesScreen.this);
            builder.setTitle("Add a New Class:");

            final EditText input = new EditText(classesScreen.this);

            builder.setView(input);

            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    m_text = input.getText().toString();

                    Group gru1 = new Group();
                    gru1.setName(m_text);

                    child_list = new ArrayList<Child>();

                    Child ch1 = new Child();
                    ch1.setName("Yo");

                    child_list.add(ch1);

                    gru1.setItems(child_list);

                    group_list.add(gru1);
                    ExpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
       });
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){}

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
}
```

I also have two object class called Group and Child. I can show those if you need them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "How to save an expandable listview in android?" -- you don't. You save the model data that is used to populate the `ExpandableListView`. In your case, that is saving the `Group` and `Child` objects. "I have tried using sharedpreferences with gson to json, however that doesn't seem to work" -- we cannot help you with code that we cannot see. `SharedPreferences` would seem to be an odd choice. You may as well save the data to a plain JSON file (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`).

Comment: Can you specify why you couldnt save it using gson and sharedpreferences?

Comment: @CommonsWare how would I go about saving the group and child objects, and then retrieving them and populating the expandable list again?

Comment: Um, save the data to a SQLite database, or a JSON file, or an XML file, or perhaps `SharedPreferences`, or perhaps something else. Load it back in using the same mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make ur model class implement Serializable

Save your latest arrayList into a file

```
    private void saveDataToFile() {

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = getContext().openFileOutput("fileName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = null;
    try {
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {

    }
    try {
        if (objectOutputStream != null) {
            objectOutputStream.writeObject(yourArrayList); //which data u want to save
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        if (objectOutputStream != null) {
            objectOutputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Retrieve data from file

```
    private void getDataFromFile() {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    try {
        fileInputStream = getContext().openFileInput("fileName");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = null;
    try {
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    } catch (IOException |NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        yourArrayList = (ArrayList<YourClassName>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        objectInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: How and where would I call these methods?

Comment: when u need to save the list call saveDataToFile(). when u need to retrieve data call  getDataFromFile();

Comment: This doesn't work, I don't get any errors it just doesn't do it.

Comment: U want to save your listview object item and retrieve the data for next time app open . Is this u looking for ?

Comment: Yes, and also when the activity is changed.

Comment: U can do whatever u want to do.. save your list when u need to save retrieve when u need to retrieve. What did u mean by doesn't work?

Comment: when I close the app and reopen it the list is empty. I want it to save when the app is closed.

Comment: I figured it out, using a method similar to yours I just had to make Group serialization AND Child serialization. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention.. U have to make ur model class implement Serializable..